# How can I remove the individual input box through the jquery remove function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Here is my code. In that code the remove function works on only one input box, however I want that, it work on every input box which created through the append function.

```
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){




            var one=1;

            $("#add").click(function(){
                one++;
               $("#form_value").append("<div id=\"man"+one+"\"><br><input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Product\"name=\"product["+one+"]\"><div class=\"w3-col l4\"> <input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Product description\"></div><button type=\"button\" id=\"rem"+one+"\">Remove</button></div>");


                 $("#rem"+one+"").click(function(){


                $("#man"+one+"").remove();

            });  

            });





        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the value of `one` will increase each time you click on the add button, and this is the value that is used within the remove event.

If you add `console.log(one)` within the remove event you will see that `one` is always the last number.

A better way to do this would be to assign the div/remove elements to jquery objects and remove that instead.

e.g.

```js
var one = 1;

$("#add").click(function() {
  one++;
  var $div = $("<div id='man" + one + "'></div>");
  
  $div.append("<br><input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Product\"name=\"product[" + one + "]\"><div class=\"w3-col l4\"> <input type=\"text\" placeholder=\"Product description\"></div>");

  var $remove =
    $("<button type='button' id='rem" + one + "'>Remove</button>")
    .click(function() {
      $div.remove();
    });

  $("#form_value").append($div.append($remove));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form_value"></div>
<button id="add">Add</button>
```